# Interval aggregation of 5 minutes for last 24 hours in database

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to aggregate the data for last 24 hours on 5 min interval basis. I had written following query:

```
select  
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', t.datetime) / 5 * 5, '2000') 
as datetimevalue,    
    cast(sum(t.value) as decimal(10,2)) as value 
from 
    dbo.data t  
where 
    t.datetime <= '2020-09-12 19:23:00.000' 
    and t.datetime > DATEADD(day,-1,'2020-09-12 19:23:00.000')    
group by
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', t.datetime) / 5 * 5, '2000')   
order by 
    datetimevalue asc
```

The result is returned like this:

```
datetimevalue               value
------------------------------------
2020-09-12 18:45:00.000,    54227.16
2020-09-12 18:50:00.000,    53681.54
2020-09-12 18:55:00.000,    49379.01
2020-09-12 19:00:00.000,    50751.53
2020-09-12 19:05:00.000,    55033.14
2020-09-12 19:10:00.000,    55858.37
2020-09-12 19:15:00.000,    54236.57
2020-09-12 19:20:00.000,    26731.36
```

I need aggregation of last 5 minute starting from current timestamp insteead of above which is aggregating last 3 minutes and then 5 minutes after that.

For example

```
datetimevalue               value
--------------------------------------
2020-09-12 19:03:00.000,    22444.47
2020-09-12 19:08:00.000,    45674.46
2020-09-12 19:13:00.000,    35737.23
2020-09-12 19:18:00.000,  34675.34
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the offset to the aggregation time window (5 minutes), substract it while calculating values and the add it again to the final times:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @offset INT = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CAST(@dt AS DATE) AS DATETIME), @dt) % (60 * 5)) / 60 * 60
-- In case you want an offset in seconds
--DECLARE @diff INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CAST(@dt AS DATE) AS DATETIME), @dt) % (60 * 5)


SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, @offset, datetimevalue) AS datetimevalue, value
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', DATEADD(SECOND, -@offset, t.DATETIME)) / 5 * 5, '2000') AS datetimevalue
       ,cast(sum(t.value) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS value
    FROM dbo.data t
    WHERE t.DATETIME <= @dt
    -- in case you want only for last 24 hours
    --  AND t.DATETIME > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, @dt)
    -- in case if you want to include offset in last timestamp
        AND t.DATETIME > DATEADD(SECOND, -@offset, DATEADD(DAY, - 1, @dt))
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', DATEADD(SECOND, -@offset, t.DATETIME)) / 5 * 5, '2000')
    ) T
ORDER BY datetimevalue DESC
```

Comment: I executed above query, if current timestamp is ```2020-09-13 06:52:13.663```, i am getting last record with timestamp as ```2020-09-12 06:52:00.000```which should be ```2020-09-12 06:47:00.000```, if aggregation is of last 5 mintutes from ```2020-09-13 06:52:13.663```

Comment: I think you would be covering more than 24 hours, anyway, if that's the requirement you could manage that by applying the offset in the filter. I mean, replace t.DATETIME > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, @dt) with DATEADD(SECOND, -@offset, DATEADD(DAY, - 1, @dt)) .

Comment: you can make you answer more valuable by providing the changes which need to be done if I want to aggregate on 10, 15 minute instead of 5 minutes.